# how to check a switch or router using SSH or telnet in python

Tags: python

now have to hard code telnet or ssh, how to auto know whether it is using ssh or telnet and then decide to use ssh or telnet

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import getpass
import pexpect
import sys
import os
```

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are asking, and appears as this is a python specific question (instead of Ubuntu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import socket
import subprocess
ClientSocket = socket.socket()
try:
    ClientSocket.connect(("remote_host", 22))
    port = 22
except socket.error:
    ClientSocket.connect(("remote_host", 23))
    port = 23
finally:
    command = "sshpass -ppassword ssh -t -t username@remote_host -p {0}".format(port).split()
    subprocess.call(command)
    ClientSocket.close()
```

Here we are at first trying that whether port 22 **(SSH)** is open on the remote host, if open jump to the `finally` segment, if it raises an exception check whether port 23 **(Telnet)** is open and then go to `finally`. In the `finally` segment we are using `sshpass` program (you need to install it manually by `sudo apt-get install sshpass`, if not installed) to provide the password directly in the command, you can also use the **paramiko** module of python here.

**Security concern:** you should not give your password as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196105/python-how-to-check-if-a-network-port-is-open-on-linux) may enlight your problem, just adapt the code to your needs. For example:

```
import socket

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if sck.connect_ex(('some_host_name_or_ip', 23)) == 0:
    ## Telnet is open do telnet related stuff here

sck.close()

sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if sck.connect_ex(('some_host_name_or_ip', 22)) == 0:
    # SSH is open do ssh related stuff here

sck.close()
```

Comment: My fault, too many tabs open. Corrected. Many thanks